# A space $X$ is contractible if and only if it is homotopically equivalent to the space with one point.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I understand that for $\{pt\}\rightarrow X \rightarrow \{pt\}$ we can compose the inclusion map with the constant map and get the identity. However, for $X\rightarrow \{pt\} \rightarrow X$, I do not understand how we can get a continuous mapping from $\{pt\}$ to $X$ that, when composed with the constant map, give us the identity for all of $X$. Could someone convince me of this?

Comment: What is your definition of contractible?

Comment: In any case, that composition does.not have to be equal to the identity, only homotopic to it. In all but trivial cases the composition is certainly not the identity map.

Comment: Take the maps $f: X \rightarrow \{a\}$ and $g: \{a\} \rightarrow X$. By assumption, we know g(f) is homotopic to identity map on $X$. So consider $g(f(x))$. You will see that this is in fact a constant map and by assumption it is homotopic to the identity map. Thus, contractible.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of "homotopy equivalence" does not require the composition $X\to\{pt\}\to X$ to be the identity map; it only required it to be *homotopic* to the identity map.  That is, there should be a homotopy from the identity map $X\to X$ to a constant map.  This is exactly what a contraction gives you.